# add two different textboxes aligned to image top and bottom

Tags: minipage

How can I achieve this kind of layout?

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ here           │ zero, one or more            │
│ is always      │ lines of wrapping text       │
│ a half         │ aligned top                  │
│ page size      │                              │
│ image          │                              │
│ displayed      │ one line text bottom aligned │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

I thought of using minipages, but am not sure if and how that's doable.

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ here           │ zero, one or more            │
│ is always      │ lines of text                │
│ a half         │──────────────────────────────┘
│ page size      │                              
│ image          │──────────────────────────────┐
│ displayed      │ one line text bottom aligned │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Are there any other common approaches I can use? The upper textbox needs can have several lines, one or none. The lower textbox is always filled with one line of text. Both boxes and the free space between them combined should have the same height as the image on the left of them.

Edit: spelling corrected, and with half page size I meant that I want to be able to add two of these constructs on one page.

Comment: Your write-up is not entirely clear. First, did you mean to write "archive" or "achieve"? Second, more importantly, what does "half page size" refer to: Half the height of the *page*, half the height of the *text block* (i.e., exclude the height of header and footer), or something else? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newlength\graphicheight
\setlength\graphicheight{\heightof{%
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}%
\quad%
\begin{minipage}[b][\graphicheight][b]{\linegoal}
\lipsum[1][1-3] \par\vfill \lipsum[2][1]    
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit cumbersome to implement

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-
sectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adip-
iscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.49\textwidth}
  \text
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.49\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \text
  \end{minipage}%
  \vfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t][1em]{\textwidth}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```